# How can I make a perl script that will rename files in a specific directory every couple minutes?

Tags: perl, file, cgi

I wanted to add a live picture rotation to my site and i could not find any other way to do it so i decided that i need a cgi script that will:
1. Delete the first picture in the rotation (e.g. pic1.jpg)
2. Rename the rest of the pictures (e.g. rename pic2.jpg to pic1.jpg, pic3.jpg to pic2.jpg, pic4.jpg to pic3.jpg, etc...)
3. Do this every 5 minutes so that the viewers of my site will all be viewing the same picture pretty much at the sime time.
Any help will be much appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a pretty bad idea, frankly. File operations are relatively slow, and tends to step on itself in a highly-concurrent application like a webapp.

Look for another way. How about using the current time as a key to choose among pictures?

```
currentImageIndex = currentTimeRoundedToTheNearestFiveMinutes %
                    totalNumberOfImages
```

**Edited** with more detail on request:

Basically, take the current time, and round it to the nearest five minutes. Doing something like `currentHour / 12`, using integer math, will give you this; otherwise, truncate the result. Then use the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator (`%` in Perl, and many languages - handy operator that newcomers tend to overlook) to produce a number from `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is the total number of images you're serving. Then you can refer to a mapping table to go from that index to a filename.

Comment: thanks for answering, I am very curios about this method. Say i used the current time, could I still make the pictures live so that everyone is viewing the same one?

Comment: @James: yep. Since the current server time, when rounded to the nearest five (or whatever you like) minutes, is the same for all users browsing at the same time, everyone will see the same image.

Comment: Until the next five-minute slice, when everyone will see the same *next* image.

Comment: oh, thank you, i think i would rather use that method. I would much appreciate it if you could give me some more detailed code to use so i can program it better since i'm new to perl.

Comment: @James: I don't know Perl, so I can't help you there. The basic concepts are quite simple, though - you should be able to translate this into code easily, if you have any basis in Perl (and if you don't, get a grounding first before you build a webapp :-) )

Answer (score 2):

To make this work "so that the viewers of my site will all be viewing the same picture pretty much at the same time", you need to use different urls for each image or make sure you are telling browsers and proxies not to cache the pictures...and not caching is a really bad idea; your viewers will not appreciate it, nor will your server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am alright with using different urls for each image.

Comment: @James - then you have no need to rename the files

Comment: oh, well i want the pictures to be live so that everyone sees the same one at the same time so i need the images to rotate.

Comment: @James: do it in javascript, then

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in a comment that you don't need caching, rather than change the filenames of each file, why not have your page point to a file which is a symlink and then change the pointer of the symlink every few minutes. Seems like it would do what you need without the overhead of major file operations.